# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined | Failed to compile - ReactApp

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, babeljs, babel-loader

I've got this message when I try to compile my React Application :

[image]

I tried to update npm, install eveything I can but it's still not working...

Just there, the code of my error :

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
at isForInRef (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:406)
at variable.references.some.ref (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:443)
at Array.some (<anonymous>)
at isUsedVariable (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:442)
at collectUnusedVariables (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:565)
at collectUnusedVariables (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:572)
at Program:exit (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:617)
at listeners.(:3000/anonymous function).forEach.listener (/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/safe-emitter.js:47:58)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.emit (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/safe-emitter.js:47)
at NodeEventGenerator.applySelector (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:251)
at NodeEventGenerator.applySelectors (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:280)
at NodeEventGenerator.leaveNode (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:303)
at CodePathAnalyzer.leaveNode (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/code-path-analysis/code-path-analyzer.js:630)
at CodePathAnalyzer.overrideLeaveNode (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint-plugin-node/lib/rules/process-exit-as-throw.js:127)
at Traverser.leave [as _leave] (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter.js:868)
at isForInRef (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:406)
at variable.references.some.ref (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:443)
at Array.some (<anonymous>)
at isUsedVariable (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:442)
at collectUnusedVariables (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:565)
at collectUnusedVariables (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:572)
at Program:exit (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/rules/no-unused-vars.js:617)
at listeners.(:3000/anonymous function).forEach.listener (/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/safe-emitter.js:47:58)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Object.emit (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/safe-emitter.js:47)
at NodeEventGenerator.applySelector (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:251)
at NodeEventGenerator.applySelectors (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:280)
at NodeEventGenerator.leaveNode (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/node-event-generator.js:303)
at CodePathAnalyzer.leaveNode (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/code-path-analysis/code-path-analyzer.js:630)
at CodePathAnalyzer.overrideLeaveNode (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint-plugin-node/lib/rules/process-exit-as-throw.js:127)
at Traverser.leave [as _leave] (:3000/Users/lucasgoncalves/GitHub Local/C-D-localhost/Client/node_modules/eslint/lib/linter.js:868)
at Object../src/layouts/popup.js (index.js:8)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 67fb8c2d093d03f17433:678)
at fn (bootstrap 67fb8c2d093d03f17433:88)
at Object../src/pages/main.page.js (login.page.js:9)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 67fb8c2d093d03f17433:678)
at fn (bootstrap 67fb8c2d093d03f17433:88)
at Object../src/App.js (fetch.js:461)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 67fb8c2d093d03f17433:678)
at fn (bootstrap 67fb8c2d093d03f17433:88)
at Object../src/index.js (index.css?f255:26)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 67fb8c2d093d03f17433:678)
at fn (bootstrap 67fb8c2d093d03f17433:88)
at Object.0 (store.js:215)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 67fb8c2d093d03f17433:678)
at bootstrap 67fb8c2d093d03f17433:724
at bootstrap 67fb8c2d093d03f17433:724
```

I've checked everything I found on Stack but I can't find a topic who help me to fix this issue...

Thanks for your help, and I'm sorry if this kind of topic already exist, I can't found it before :/

Comment: Could you please add script from image file.GuestBook.jsx

Comment: Please add the Guestbook code as well

Comment: Here the file: https://gist.github.com/igwall/f01228fbd71e088a97e4d1fe9f1f1539

Thanks for your help :)